# Update TSSTcorp CDDVD Drivers

Tags: windows, dvd, compact-disc

I've got installed a DVD-Writer:

```
TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-216AB
```

Windows says me that the installed Drivers are current (6.1.7600), but another website tells me the newest driver is more than 7.x and from 2012. Now if I tell Windows to download the newest drivers it says that these are already the newest.

So where are those new drivers downloadable?

Comment: 1. What version of Windows are you running? 2. Why do you need new drivers? 3. What website is telling you that there is a more current driver version? 4. Are you attempting to update the driver through Device Manager? If you can download the driver you can try to install it manually in Device Manager.

Comment: Drivers are native to each OS, those version numbers are Windows OS versions, no need to update optical drive drivers as there are none available to download, nor are they needed.

Comment: I am running Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a specific problem with your DVD burner, and know that the new drivers will fix it, leave it alone.  The drivers windows installed automatically should work just fine, and are likely to be stable and fairly bug free.  Just because some website or utility says there are newer drivers, doesn't mean you need them.

Version 6.1.7600 is also the version number for windows 7, so I suspect that you are running windows 7, and these are the drivers from Microsoft to support a DVD burner.  There is almost never a good reason not to use those drivers.

Comment: I am running Windows 7 and I habe a Problem with this Optical Drive and iTunes, as I mentioned in this Question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63830/itunes-not-working-propperly-with-tsstcorp-cddvd-device

Comment: I found a Page which another User has actually similar Problems and he told the board that updating the optical drivers wpuld help. The Page which showed me the versions is this one: http://drivers.awdit.de/tsstcorp/tsstcorp-cddvdw-sh-216ab/

Comment: In that case, it's not a problem of drivers, but of filters.  http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/ht/upperfilters-lowerfilters.htm tells you how to remove them.  When finished, you might need to reinstall itunes.

Comment: I already tried this, the Filters are not there. If I add them, the iTunes error does not appear again, but iPhone still does not get recognized and also my TSSTcorp devide shows an error Code 19.

Comment: @Florian: In general if you have problems with an optical drive update it's firmware but leave the driver alone.